# How to colour and insert text for specific data points in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my data

```
varechem <-
  structure(
    list(
      `POX-C` = c(
        869.153225806452,
        841.409274193548,
        720.344758064516,
        828.798387096774,
        904.46370967742,
        773.310483870968,
        793.487903225806,
        874.197580645161,
        900.932661290323,
        778.354838709677
      ),
      `B-glucosidase` = c(
        1.90612612612613,
        1.60509009009009,
        1.42864864864865,
        1.82355855855856,
        1.76761261261261,
        1.34855855855856,
        1.37504504504504,
        1.5863963963964,
        1.1290990990991,
        1.4686036036036
      ),
      Protein = c(
        6284.21052631579,
        6250.52631578947,
        6103.15789473684,
        6280,
        6275.78947368421,
        4368.42105263158,
        1240,
        6191.57894736842,
        5745.26315789474,
        6970.52631578947
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(
      "M.T1.R1.S1.16S.S50",
      "M.T1.R1.S2.16S.S62",
      "M.T1.R1.S3.16S.S74",
      "M.T1.R2.S1.16S.S86",
      "M.T1.R2.S2.16S.S3",
      "M.T1.R2.S3.16S.S15",
      "M.T1.R3.S1.16S.S27",
      "M.T1.R3.S2.16S.S39",
      "M.T1.R3.S3.16S.S51",
      "M.T1.R4.S1.16S.S63"
    ),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

varespec <-
  structure(
    list(
      A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      B = c(1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      C = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            3),
      D = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      E = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            3, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      F = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      G = c(1,
            1, 11, 20, 15, 13, 23, 9, 1, 16),
      H = c(2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1),
      I = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      J = c(9, 3, 20,
            21, 16, 19, 22, 13, 12, 26)
    ),
    row.names = c(
      "M.T1.R1.S1.16S.S50",
      "M.T1.R1.S2.16S.S62",
      "M.T1.R1.S3.16S.S74",
      "M.T1.R2.S1.16S.S86",
      "M.T1.R2.S2.16S.S3",
      "M.T1.R2.S3.16S.S15",
      "M.T1.R3.S1.16S.S27",
      "M.T1.R3.S2.16S.S39",
      "M.T1.R3.S3.16S.S51",
      "M.T1.R4.S1.16S.S63"
    ),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

I have my codes:

```
library(vegan); library(ggplot2)
sol <- cca(varespec, varechem)
scrs <- scores(sol, display = c("sp", "wa", "lc", "bp", "cn"))
df_sites <- data.frame(scrs$sites)
df_sites$Sites <- gsub("\\..*", "", rownames(varechem))

df_sites$Sites <- factor(df_sites$Sites)
# rownames(df_sites) <- gsub("[*].*$", "",rownames(df_sites))
colnames(df_sites) <- c("x", "y", "Sites")

#Draw sites
p <- ggplot()
p <-
  p + geom_point(
    data = df_sites,
    aes(x, y, colour = Sites),
    shape = "diamond",
    size = 2
  )
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue"), guide = FALSE)
p

#Draw biplots
multiplier <- vegan:::ordiArrowMul(scrs$biplot)

df_arrows <- scrs$biplot * multiplier
colnames(df_arrows) <- c("x", "y")
df_arrows = as.data.frame(df_arrows)


#adding arrows for chemicals (environment variables)
pa <-
  p + geom_segment(
    data = df_arrows,
    aes(
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      xend = x,
      yend = y
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")),
    arrow.fill = "black"
  )
pa

###adjust the position of the labels or shapes
df_arrows <- as.data.frame(df_arrows * 1.1)
df_arrows$Chemicals <- factor(rownames(df_arrows))
cp <-
  pa + geom_point(data = df_arrows,
                  aes(x, y, group = Chemicals, shape = Chemicals),
                  size = 4) + scale_shape_manual(values = 1:nlevels(df_arrows$Chemicals))


#### # Draw species
df_species <- as.data.frame(scrs$species)
colnames(df_species) <- c("x", "y")


significant_taxa <- c("A", "D")

df_species$significant <-
  ifelse(rownames(df_species) %in% significant_taxa, "Sig", "Not-sig")

df_species$significant <- as.character(df_species$significant)

get.colour <- c("red", "orange")
# scp <- cp + geom_point(data = df_species, aes(x, y), size = 0.5)

#relevel factor so "Sig" will appear first in the legend
df_species$significant <-
  factor(df_species$significant, levels = c("Sig", "Not-sig"))
df_species$coloured <- "black"
df_species$coloured [match(significant_taxa, rownames(df_species))] <-
  get.colour
df_species$coloured <- as.factor(df_species$coloured)
```

This is where I need help. I need to put two colours for siginficant values
(`Sig` only) from `df_species$coloured` and get their labels from the dataframe
rownames(df_species) which is A and D in their respective font colours. So I
would like to put two colours and text associated with that `A` and `D`. How
can I do this?

```
scp <- cp + geom_point(data = df_species, aes(x, y, group = significant, size = significant)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(4.5, 0.2))
scp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution. I added an extra column to `df_species` to create the labels in the plot.

```
df_species <- df_species %>% 
  mutate(labels = rownames(df_species))
```

The plot: (This part is updated based on the comment of the OP.)

```
scp <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df_species,
             aes(x = x,
                 y = y,
                 colour = coloured,
                 size = significant)) +
  geom_text(data = subset(df_species, significant == "Sig"),
            aes(x = x,
                y = y,
                label = labels,
                colour = coloured),
            hjust = 1,
            vjust = -1,
           show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black" = "black", "red" = "red", "orange" = "orange")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(4.5, 0.2)) +
  geom_point(data = df_sites,
             aes(x = x,
                 y = y,
                 fill = Sites),
             size = 2,
             pch = 23) + # with this shape you can use fill
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("M" = "blue")) +
  geom_point(data = df_arrows,
             aes(x = x, 
                 y = y, 
                 group = Chemicals, 
                 shape = Chemicals),
             size = 4) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1:nlevels(df_arrows$Chemicals)) +
  geom_segment(data = df_arrows,
               aes(x = 0,
                   y = 0,
                   xend = x,
                   yend = y),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")),
               arrow.fill = "black")

scp
```

It took a bit of playing around, but I hope this is what you where looking for. :-) I added everything together. For me this was a bit easier to get the overview. The position / order of the `scale_*` functions is important.

[image]

Comment: It is close, but I would like Sites 'M' in a separate legend called `Sites` and the rest of the colours in another legend.